# Google play service mistakenly deleted from sdk manager

Tags: android, sdk

I deleted Google play service and Google repository from SDK manager of android studio and I don't know how to re-install them.
can anybody help me to find how to make these items reappear in SDK manager?

Comment: restart your Android Studio and go to your Toolbar and from SDK Manager you will be able to install then again

Comment: i did so many times. but no trace of google play service under extras forlder

Answer (score 0):

Go to android sdk manager

select GooglePlayService and install it.

Internet Connection required.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: dear friend my question was that i have deleted this pack mistakenly by selecting that and deleting it by "Delete 1 package" from below button. and i don't know how to add this package once again to sdk manager